# Некорректная длина массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется генератор массива, который при получении строки 'odd' или 'even' должен выводить массив только из нечетных или четных чисел. Сам код работает, но длина массива вместо 10 постоянно разная, в диапазоне от 2 до 8, а требуется чтобы было именно 10, как и передаем функцию. В чем ошибка? Перерыл весь Google, но не смог найти ответ. Заранее спасибо

```js
'use strict';

const generateArray3 = (lengthArray, n, m, parity) => {
    let array = [];
    let evenArray = [];
    let oddArray = [];
   
    for (let i = 0; i < lengthArray; i++) {
      array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - m + 1)) + m);
      if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        evenArray.push(array[i]);
      } else {
        oddArray.push(array[i]);
      }
    }

    if (parity === 'even') {
        return evenArray;
    } else {
        return oddArray;
    }
}

console.log(generateArray3(10, -5, 25, 'even'));
console.log(generateArray3(10, -5, 25, 'odd'));
```

Comment: У вас цикл неверный. Цикл отработает 10 итераций, а вот добавлять значения или нет определяется внутри if. Замените цикл for на цикл `while ()`. И записывать лучше в один массив и его же возвращать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас цикл неверный.

Цикл отработает 10 итераций, а вот добавлять значения или нет определяется внутри if.

Вам надо заменить цикл **for** на цикл **while**.

Так же, использование нескольких массивов не целесообразно, можно работать с одним.

```js
const generateArray3 = (lengthArray, n, m, parity) => {
  const array = [];

  while (array.length < lengthArray) {
    const val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - m + 1)) + m;
    if ((parity === 'even' && !(val % 2)) || (parity === 'odd' && val % 2)) {
      array.push(val);
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(generateArray3(10, -5, 25, 'even'));
console.log(generateArray3(10, -5, 25, 'odd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты используешь значение `lengthArray` как количество попыток генерации чисел, а не как конечную длину массива. В итоге получается `lengthArray` равно сумме длин `evenArray` и `oddArray`, а поскольку оба они почти 100% больше 0, то и получается, что другой меньше 10.

Замени for на  `while (result_array.length < lengthArray)`. Ну и нет смысла создавать два массива, т.е. нужен все равно только один.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том что вы строите `lengthArray` значений распределяете их по двум массивам. Сумма длин массивов - ровно `lengthArray`. Затем вы возвращаете один из массивов ожидая что его длина будет равна `lengthArray`. Такое возможно, но случается редко.

Функция `makeGen(n, m, even)` возвращает генератор случайных чисел в диапазоне [n, m]. Если флаг `even === true` генератор порождает только чётные числа, если `even === false` - только нечётные.

Генератор очень упрощает функцию `generateArray3` - создаём генератор, вызываем его столько раз, сколько нужно:

```js
const makeGen = (n, m, even) => {
    let a = Math.min(n, m);
    if ((a % 2 === 0) !== even) {
        ++a;
    }
    let b = Math.max(n, m);
    if ((b % 2 === 0) !== even) {
        --b;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        throw new RangeError("empty range");
    }
    const k = (b - a) / 2 + 1;
    return () => a + 2 * Math.floor(Math.random() * k);
};

const generateArray3 = (lengthArray, n, m, parity) => {
    let even;
    if (parity === 'even') {
        even = true;
    } else if (parity === 'odd') {
        even = false;
    } else {
        throw new RangeError("parity is not 'even' or 'odd'");
    }
    const gen = makeGen(n, m, even);

    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lengthArray; ++i) {
        array.push(gen());
    }
    return array;
};

console.log(generateArray3(10, -5, 25, 'even'));
console.log(generateArray3(10, -5, 25, 'odd'));
```